# Taking a photo via intent drastically worsens the photo quality?

Tags: android, android-camera

I have an application that I'm running on Rock960 (Android SBC). With a button click, I call the `dispatchTakePictureIntent(View View)` function to initialize everything that is needed for my app to take a photo. I'm using a Logitech C270 Webcam. It doesn't have autofocus BUT I have fixed the distance from the camera to the object I'm taking photos of, and when I see the camera preview, everything is in focus.

The problem now is this: When I click my button, I can see that the object is in focus. However, when I click the "take photo" icon, the app takes a photo and shows me what it took, and I can cancel, accept, or retake. The photo it shows, however, tends to be very very bad in quality. It's as if it tried to take a photo again but failed in doing so.

Here are the relevant code in my app:

```
public void dispatchTakePictureIntent(View view) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent

    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, 1024);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",   /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    Log.e(TAG, "mCurrentPhotoPath is = " + mCurrentPhotoPath);

    return image;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 1024) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Log.e(TAG, "result from camera is OK!");
            //  Prepare the Tesseract Files
            prepareTessData();
            startOCR();
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Result canceled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activity result failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}

private void startOCR(){
    try{
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = 6;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath, options);
        String result = this.getText(bitmap);
        textView.setText(result);
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Manifest File:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

Now, I'm not sure what's happening here. May it be because my camera doesn't have autofocus? This code works fine in Android Tablets and Mobile Phones, however, it's acting up with my Rock960.

Comment: are pics good if you take with the camera app on your phone? How are you using the returned value?

Comment: @Blackbelt When I just use the camera app on my board, the quality is good, it doesn't change. When I get a positive result, I'm actually using the path I made, decode it as bitmap, and use the Tesseract Library to run OCR. I'll update my question shortly.

Comment: `options.inSampleSize = 6;` this makes your bitmap 1/6 in width and height. Are you aware of that?

Comment: Even after commenting out `options.inSampleSize = 6`, the image taken after clicking the "take photo" icon still is subpar.

Comment: out of curiosity, how do you know that the picture has low quality?

Answer (score 0):

**The image provided in the data extra is only a [thumbnail](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPhotoView). To obtain the fullsize image you need to provide a fully qualified file name where the camera app should save the photo. This is described in the documentation, with example code provided.**

Comment: Uhhhh you mean like the `createImageFile` function I have in my code that's exactly the same as the one in the documentation?

Comment: Read the documentation which is provided by me in the answer